# Was there ever a version of C++ that kept a variable declared in the initialization of a for loop in scope after the loop ended?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, for-loop, visual-studio-2008

For example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    //Do something with i
}

cout << i;
```

Would this have ever been valid? I am trying to get 15 year old c++ to compile in a modern (if you consider Visual Studio 2008 modern) IDE and it is complaining about something like this.

Comment: `i` is out of scope of its declaration i.e in `for` loop.

Answer (score 4):

That's a compiler specific feature (i.e. language extension). To "allow" it for Visual C++ you would set the [`/Zc:forScope-`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/84wcsx8x.aspx) flag or the [`/Ze`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k0w269d.aspx) flag. Setting this flag enables the language extension to allow the scope of the variables defined in the `for` loop to extend past that loop (but won't necessarily work in other compilers).

Comment: "Language extensions" are not allowed to break compliant C++ code. This feature of Microsoft compiler does break compliant C++ code (e.g. it prevents `for(int i;0;); int i;` from compiling), which formally disqualifies it from being an extension. It could be called a "dialect", but not an extension.

Comment: @AnT, the MSDN article for the `/Ze` flag specifically states "disable language extensions" and more specifically calls them "constructs that are not compatible with ANSI C89 or ISO C++11" .. Wasn't trying to be 100% pedantic in the answer, just quoting MSDN :)

Comment: Well, that simply means that Microsoft misused the term "extension". One cannot just take any deviation from language spec and slap an "extension" label on it. There are extra requirements that "extensions" are supposed to meet in order to qualify as such. And Microsoft's treatment of cycle variables does not meet these requirements.

Comment: Regarless of what it is called, the `/Zc:forScope-` flag made the old code compile. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this was a bug in early Microsoft compilers. The workaround is simple: just move the declaration of the loop control variable outside the loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
}
cout << i;
```

becomes

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {                                        
}
cout << i;
```

Comment: This is what I was doing until I saw the flag @txtechhelp mentioned. My goal was to modify the original code as little as possible before I got it to compile. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @benjamincuningham - the flag will, I assume, get it to work with Microsoft compilers, but that won't help if you have to move it to some other compiler. It's really up to you...

Answer (score 1):

No, there never was such version of C++. In all versions of C++ language the scope of such variable was explicitly restricted  to the loop.

Every time you see the scope of such loop variable extended beyond the loop, it is a bug in the compiler (as was the case in older versions of Microsoft compiler).